# Spring Mongodb: configure documents to use specific dbs?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-session

I have a rest based spring-boot microservice that I want to configure to store authentication and session data in one mongo database and application data in another database.

My current setup mostly works, except that spring is creating all of my documents in both databases.  I looked at the `@Document()` annotation, but it does not have a parameter for the database to use.

**In mongo shell:**

```
> show dbs
admin                 0.000GB
authentication        0.000GB
prospect              0.000GB

> use authentication
switched to db authentication

> show collections
credentials
credentials_authorities
prospects
roles
sessions

> use prospect
switched to db prospect

> show collections
prospects
```

**application.properties:**

```
com.mycompany.prospect.domainName=mycompany.com

spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb-service
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

com.mycompany.prospect.server.appDatabase=prospect
com.mycompany.prospect.server.sessionDatabase=authentication
```

**HttpSessionConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoHttpSession()
public class HttpSessionConfig {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @Bean
  public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer(
      @Value("${com.mycompany.prospect.domainName:localhost}")
          final String domainName) {

    logger.info("Configuring DefaultCookieSerializer with DomainName '{}'.", domainName);

    final DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setDomainName(domainName);
    serializer.setUseHttpOnlyCookie(true);
    return serializer;
  }

  @Bean
  public JdkMongoSessionConverter jdkMongoSessionConverter() {
    return new JdkMongoSessionConverter();
  }
}
```

**MongoConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfig {

  private final Environment env;

  public MongoConfig(Environment env) {
    this.env = env;
  }

  @Bean("applicationTemplate")
  @Qualifier("applicationTemplate")
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(
      final MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter, final MongoClient mongoClient) {
    final String databaseName =
        env.getRequiredProperty("com.mycompany.prospect.server.appDatabase");

    final MongoDbFactory dbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, databaseName);
    return new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
  }

  @Bean("mongoOperations")
  @Qualifier("mongoOperations")
  @Primary
  public MongoTemplate mongoOperations(
      final MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter, final MongoClient mongoClient) {
    final String databaseName =
        env.getRequiredProperty("com.mycompany.prospect.server.sessionDatabase");
    final MongoDbFactory dbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, databaseName);
    final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
    return mongoTemplate;
  }    
}
```

**Prospect.java**

```
@Document(collection = "prospects")
public class Prospect {
  @Id private String prospectId;

  @TextIndexed() private String businessName;

  public String getProspectId() {
    return prospectId;
  }

  public void setProspectId(String prospectId) {
    this.prospectId = prospectId;
  }

  public String getBusinessName() {
    return businessName;
  }

  public void setBusinessName(final String businessName) {
    this.businessName = businessName;
  }
}
```

I would like for the prospects collection to only exist in the prospect database.

I've tried dropping the databases and restarting the services, but they come back on restart.  Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application points to a single mongodb instance and you want to switch database based on each web request. You can take a look at this sample example, 
https://github.com/Loki-Afro/multi-tenant-spring-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/zarathustra/mongo/MultiTenantMongoDbFactory.java

*PS:- I found this, When I was doing research for achieving multi-tenancy*

Comment: Thank you for an interesting find, but I'm not sure if/how this helps me.

Comment: There are 2 ways to solve the problem, 1) Instantiate a single mongoTemplate instance and switch the database at runtime before performing save operation of Prospect object (tedious). 2) Separate your session related code in to a module and your app domain models in to another module. Instantiate the mongoTemplate in each of these modules and restrict the scope of MongoTemplate to scan only the packages within each module, For example, @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.module.session", mongoTemplateRef = "sessionMongoTemplate") . This way the entries will be made in appropriate db.

Comment: Ahah!  #2 is what I was looking for.  I don't think #1 would work because spring is creating empty collections on startup.  I assume this is part of ensuring the indexes are set up properly.  I'll give #2 a go and select this answer if everything works out.

Comment: So, I adopted this approach....but spring is still creating collections in both the session and prospect DBs.

Comment: If you can upload your sample code in github I can take a look and help you with that.

Comment: Thank you so much  -- I won't have time to upload a stripped down version of my problem until this weekend.  Let me know if that's okay.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I can take a look at the code if you have it ready.